# Different forms of the covariant derivative

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, covariance

I am working through lecture notes on General Relativity and I am at the section on covariant derivatives.

I know that the following is true:
$$V_{\mu;\nu} = \frac{\partial V_{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}} - \Gamma^{\sigma}_{~\mu\nu} V_{\sigma}$$

and also that 
$$V^{\mu}_{~;\nu} = \frac{\partial V^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}} +\Gamma^{\mu}_{~\sigma\nu} V^{\sigma}.$$

My question is what happens when the derivative index is raised instead, i.e. what is $$V_{\alpha}^{~;\beta}$$.

Also, is there an easy way to arrive at the answer, such as mutliplying by the metric tensor?

Comment: $V_\alpha^{;\beta} = g^{\beta\gamma} V_{\alpha;\gamma}$

Comment: Thanks very much @Slereah! I hoped it was this but wanted to make sure of it

Comment: @Slereah That's an Answer, no?

Comment: bit short for an answer